# Drive letter not appearing after heat-related crash

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, crash, repair

I recently had my old PC (has 3 physical hard drives partitioned into 6 partitions) off while on vacation.  When I came back, I turned it on.  I hadn't realized the room was warmer than it usually is due to hot weather while I was away.  The computer was extremely slow to start up, then it crashed.  When i rebooted, it got halfway through chkdsk on one of the non-system partitions, then crashed again.  I opened it up and felt the hard drives and immediately shut down the computer and moved it to my basement to cool down because it was so hot.

I left it there for a length of time while I reinstalled the A/C.  I have now turned it on again.  It is working fine, and every drive except for the one with the partition that was being checked has appeared in Windows.  I scheduled chkdsk for all of the other partitions anyway, just in case, but I'm worried about that drive.  I'm pretty sure the drive itself hasn't *broken* but that crashing in the middle of a chkdsk repair may have corrupted the data.  What would you do in this situation?

Most of the data on that drive was backed up, so it's not a huge deal if I lost it, but I'd like to get it back if I could.  I also would love to regain usability of the drive, even if I have to wipe it -- but that's a last-resort sort of thing.  What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the remainder of the files off it, boot into a live cd version of linux.
Then mount the partition in linux, I have done this a few times when partitions are not accessible from windows.

If you recover the data, then format the drive.

If you can't recover the data, try a disk recover tool such as spinrite - www.grc.com, it has received great praise.

Answer (score 0):

From Administrative Tools menu (which might need to be de-hidden from Windows Explorer settings) pick "Computer Management" and there "Storage", "Disk Management". Now navigate to the problematic partition and right-click it. Pick "Properties", "Tools", "Error-checking", "Check now".

If this does not work, then it's either the Linux route or reformat. From the same tool, Disk Management, you can also select to re-format the partition.